# Scala Swing event framework - where do I add my reactors?

Tags: events, scala, scala-swing

I'm trying to catch a mouse-click even on a `Table` (which should cause a popup to be shown). The table is inside a `ScrollPane` which is (in turn) inside a `Panel`. I have added reactions to all the classes, but I can never seem to actually get a click event to be caught!

```
class MyPanel extends GridBagPanel {
  val gbc = new GridBagContraints( ... )

  add(new ScrollPane {
    reactions += {
      case MouseClicked(src, point, mod, clicks, pops) =>
        println("Scroll pops: " + pops)
    } 

    viewportView = new Table {
      reactions += {
        case MouseClicked(src, point, mod, clicks, pops) =>
          println("Table pops: " + pops)
      } 

      ...
    }

  }, gbc)

  reactions += {
    case MouseClicked(src, point, mod, clicks, pops) =>
      println("Panel pops: " + pops)
  } 
}
```

No matter where I click, nothing gets printed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK - You have to **listen** to the correct thing:

```
class MyPanel extends GridBagPanel {
  val gbc = new GridBagContraints( ... )

  val table = new Table { ... }

  add(new ScrollPane {

    viewportView = table
  }

  }, gbc)

  listenTo(table.Mouse.clicks) //THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT :-)

  reactions += {
    case MouseClicked(`table`, point, mod, clicks, pops) =>
      println("Panel pops: " + pops)
    } 
  }
}
```