# are scala's mouse events working? how?

Tags: swing, scala, mouseevent

I'm trying to create link-like label in scala. But no mouse events works for me. How are they supposed to work?

```
class Hyperlink extends Label{
text = "hyperlink"
reactions += {
    case MouseClicked(_,_,_,_,_) =>
        println("mouse clicked")}}
```

I put this in some panel and click over the label like a pro minesweeper player... and nothing shows up in console. Why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938437/scala-swing-event-framework-where-do-i-add-my-reactors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `listenTo` the relevant thing, something like:

```
listenTo(this.mouse.clicks)
```

Edit: since 2.8.0 Mouse is deprecated, use mouse instead

Comment: pretty hard to find this in the Api. There should be some reference from classes that extend Component, I think

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this should have been a comment to the previous answer, but due to my rep, i cant add comments.

this.Mouse is deprecated and this.mouse should be used instead. Also, this might be a good resource: http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/8