# Responding to key events in scala

Tags: swing, scala, keyevent

I'm experimenting with a bit of Scala gui programming (my first project in scala, so I thought I'd start with something simple). But I seem to have got stuck at something that seems like it should be relatively trivial. I have a class that extends scala.swing.MainFrame, and I'd like to detect when a user presses a key when that window has focus. Funny thing is I don't seem to be able to find any way to get that event to fire.

I found an example of how someone else had got around the problem here: http://houseofmirrors.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/src/main/scala/HouseGui.scala but they seem to have reverted to using the Java Swing API, which is a little disappointing. Does anyone know if there's a more idiomatic way of intercepting events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this required me to do the following:

```
class MyFrame extends MainFrame {

this.peer.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    def keyPressed(e:KeyEvent) {
      println("key pressed")
    }

    def keyReleased(e:KeyEvent) {
      println("key released")
    }

def keyTyped(e:KeyEvent) {
      println("key typed")
    }
 })

}
```

This only seemed to work though if there were no button objects attached to this component, or any of it's children.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work with Scala 2.9

```
package fi.harjum.swing

import scala.swing._
import scala.swing.event._
import java.awt.event._

object KeyEventTest extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    def top = new MainFrame {
        val label = new Label {
            text = "No click yet"
        }
        contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
            contents += label
            border = Swing.EmptyBorder(30,30,10,10)
            listenTo(keys)
            reactions += {
                case KeyPressed(_, Key.Space, _, _) =>
                    label.text = "Space is down"
                case KeyReleased(_, Key.Space, _, _) =>
                    label.text = "Space is up"
            }
            focusable = true
            requestFocus
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to listening to `this.keys` you should also call requestFocus on the component or set focusable=true, if it is Panel or derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you need to listen to `this.keys` (where `this` is the element of the GUI receiving the keyboard events). See the equivalent question about [mouse event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511308/are-scalas-mouse-events-working-how).

Comment: Thx Daniel, I needed this too. The scala's swing documentation is really poor.

Comment: `this.keys` doesn't seem to be a valid attribute of `scala.swing.MainFrame`. Nor does `this.Keys`, `this.Keyboard` or `this.keyboard`. Is there any documentation on this anywhere?

Comment: @Ceilingfish Not the `MainFrame`, but a `Component`: labels, panels, text areas, etc. And, of course, `this` refers to the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than falling back to java events all components have `keys` that publishes these events (so `MainFrame` does not). Not sure what the best solution is but it's always possible to wrap  everything in the frame inside a `Component` and listen to its `keys`.