# C#-like signals or AS3-like events in Scala?

Tags: events, scala, signals, dispatch

How do I implement C# style signals or AS3 style events in Scala? I mean mostly observer pattern. To dispatch change events. Thanks.

Or (what's even better) are there any libraries/framework which do just that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest reading [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) first, for inspiration and to get a taste of where things are going.

Then, have a look at [how scala-swing uses "reactions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938437/scala-swing-event-framework-where-do-i-add-my-reactors/938654#938654) to see how you can do this kind of thing in a library.

Finally, note that first-class functions make implementing the observer pattern yourself [relatively easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755453/scala-listener-observer/3755538#3755538).

Comment: thanks, the first doc is a little bit hard to read for me yet o.O sticking to functions